# A lower bound on the probability of an event?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a normal distribution $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ ($\sigma>0$). Imagine that one is playing the following "stopping game": she keeps acquiring independent signals from this normal distribution (the realizations being $X_1$, $X_2$, ...) till the sample mean $\overline X_n$ is "satisfactory", that is, she stops signal acquisition after seeing $n$ signals if and only if
$$\overline X_n\ge \mu+\frac{r}{\sqrt{n/\sigma}}\equiv Y_n,$$
where $r$ is some fixed real number.

**Question.** I was wondering if the probability of the event that "she never stops" (i.e., $\overline X_n<Y_n$ for all $n=1,2,\dots$) is (strictly) positive. If it is, is it possible to pin down the precise value for it?

It does not seem possible to derive a closed form expression for the probability of the event that "she has not yet stopped after seeing $n$ signals" and then pass $n$ to infinity to see if it converges to zero.

Could anyone give me some hint and/or suggestions on this problem? Thanks!